# C++ error, class and constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

I having trouble with constructors, I need to create 2 constructors. 
1. no-argument constructors that sets the object to a safe empty state.
2. two-argument constructor

I am getting errors, when i assign a value to an object variable.

```
CreditCard.cpp: In constructor âCreditCard::CreditCard()â:
CreditCard.cpp:8:11: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the â&â ?)
CreditCard.cpp: In constructor âCreditCard::CreditCard(long long int, char*)â:
CreditCard.cpp:15:11: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the â&â ?)
CreditCard.cpp: In member function âlong long int CreditCard::number() constâ:
CreditCard.cpp:32:12: error: argument of type âlong long int (CreditCard::)()constâ does not match âlong long intâ
```

**1.CreditCard();**

```
CreditCard::CreditCard() {
   number=0;
   strcpy(holder,"ABCD");
   balances=0;
}
```

**2. CreditCard(2 parameters)**

> ```
> CreditCard::CreditCard(long long num,char h[21]) {
>    number=num; 
>    strcpy(holder,h);
> }
> ```

**3. 3rd error**

> ```
> long long CreditCard::number() const {
>
>    return  number;
> }
> ```

Class (is in header file)

```
class CreditCard {
   long long int nubmer;
   char holder[21];
   double balances;

   public:
     /*declarations of constuctors */
     CreditCard();
     CreditCard(long long num,char h[21]);

     void charge(double c);
     void pay(double p);
     long long number() const;
     double balance() const;
     const char* name() const;
};
```

UPDATE: Had a mix up with member variables and functions (names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long long int nubmer;
```

Look closely at that line.

```
long long CreditCard::number() const {

   return  number;
}
```

This function claims it returns a `long long`, but it actually tries to return a *function*. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: That's the one. A mere typo in the member _variable_ name wouldn't cause this. That the correct name `number` is in fact a function, does.

Comment: The combination of the two errors is much harder to diagnose than either one alone.

Comment: Welp, faster by a bit and edited in the proper explanation. +1

Comment: i have used long long int CreditCard::number() const... i get the same error,

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: While true, it's still easy with experience ;)

Comment: @Hank99 That's not the bug. The bugs are the "number" was spelled incorrectly and that "CreditCard::number" is both a function and a member variable. Fix those.

Comment: so are you saying to change the variable name?

Comment: Change the name of either the member variable or the function, and make sure that the correct name is used in all places. You can use `m_number` for the member variable or perhaps `getNumber` for the function, depending on your style preferences.